# Retrieving/Reading Claim Values from ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

If I get straight into it, I've built a `RESTful` Service (`WebAPI` V2) with `basic authentication`... All is working as expected but I'm very unsure on how to retrieve values from `ClaimsPrincipal`. I've read many articles but all point to using third party libraries And/or `Identity` in `.Net`.

To keep it short and sweet, I have an `Attribute` performing necessary logic and a custom `authenticateService` which points to my `data store`.

I have an `n-tier architecture`:

1. API
2. Service
3. Business
4. Data

So I guess the first question is, how can I read the values from `ClaimsPrincipal`? (Apologies first time using Claims)

**To Note: I'm expecting this to fire on each request, there will be no `session`.**

Some logic that creates and authenticates the user (Inside `Attribute`)

```
using (var authService = new AuthenticateService())
            {
                var client = await _authenticateService.AuthenticateAsync(
                    apiKey,
                    password);

                if (client != null)
                {
                    // Create a ClaimsIdentity with all the claims for this user.
                    Claim apiKeyClaim = new Claim("API Key", apiKey);
                    Claim clientNameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, client.ClientName);
                    Claim clientKeyClaim = new Claim("Client Key", client.ClientKey);

                    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        apiKeyClaim,
                        clientNameClaim,
                        clientKeyClaim
                    };

                    // important to set the identity this way, otherwise IsAuthenticated will be false
                    // see: http://leastprivilege.com/2012/09/24/claimsidentity-isauthenticated-and-authenticationtype-in-net-4-5/
                    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
                    // AuthenticationTypes.Basic

                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    return principal;

                    //var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("CustomIdentification"),
                    //                   new[] { "SystemUser" });

                    //return principal;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

Accessing Claim Values in my `API controller`:

```
[IdentityBasicAuthentication]
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class OrderController : ApiController
    {
        private IOrderService _orderService;
        public OrderController(IOrderService orderService)
        {
            _orderService = orderService;
        }
        // POST api/<controller>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("order")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Models.Model.Order order)
        {

            var modelResponse = new ModelResponse<Models.Model.Order>(order);
            if (order == null)
                return BadRequest("Unusable resource.");

            if (!modelResponse.IsModelValid())
                return this.PropertiesRequired(modelResponse.ModelErrors());

            try
            {
                //Create abstracted Identity model to pass around layers
                // Access Claim values here
                //OR can I use Claims in other layers without creating an abstracted model to pass through.
                await _orderService.AddAsync(order);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
            finally
            {
                _orderService.Dispose();
            }

            return Ok("Order Successfully Processed.");
        }
    }
```

Really appreciate your time reading this, hopefully "someone" can direct/help me reading claim values and/or best approach to passing around layers.

Regards,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access to claims this way. In your controller method:

```
try 
{
    // ...
    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)this.RequestContext.Principal.Identity;
    foreach(var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
    {
        // claim.value;
        // claim.Type
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To be fair, I used something very similar to this. I suppose after hours and hours I went a little brain dead, Although I also added to a custom object to pass around my class libraries without adding a dependency on Claims and Identity.

Answer (score 11):

```
@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Currency").Value
```

Comment: some verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: why is there not a `bool TryGetClaim(string type, out var claim)` ?

Comment: @BozoJoe please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75551612/5404355

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering how to get the subject id from a **ClaimsPrincipal** in .net7 aspcore, it can be done as easily as this

```
var claim = principal.FindFirst(Claims.Subject); 

var id = Guid.Parse(claim?.Value ?? ""); // or cast/parse it to the expected type
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer LINQ to access
Can be found here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517271.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Useful to view all permissions & claims in Azure Functions v3 (netcore3.1). Clobbered together from various SO articles.

```cs
...
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Linq;
...
[FunctionName("AdminOnly")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> RunAdminOnly(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "test")] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log,
ClaimsPrincipal claimsID)
{
    string perms ="";
    foreach(var h in req.Headers)
    {
        perms += $"{h.Key}:{String.Join(",", h.Value)}" + "\n";
    }

    string claims = "";
    foreach (Claim claim in claimsID.Claims)
    {
        claims += $"{claim.Type} : {claim.Value} \n";
    }

    string claimDetail = "";
    Claim? appRole = claimsID.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "extension_AppRole"); // custom claim

    claimDetail += appRole?.Value.ToString();

    return new OkObjectResult(perms + "\n\n" + claims + "\n\n" + claimDetail);
}
```